# Subquery in where clause appears to be returning nothing but running the query on its own returns data

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a SQL query that has a nested select in the where clause. If I run that subquery on its own I get a row returned. However, if I run it as a nested query I get nothing returned. If I replace the nested query with the actual data that I know is returned, the query is successful.

```
select * from customers where id in (select people.id from people)
```

What I don't understand is the fact that if I run

```
select people.id from people
```

I get data, let's say ABC. If I run

```
select * from customers where id in ('ABC')
```

I get data. We're on an Oracle database, not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: Is there any row in `people` with an `id` of `null`?  F.e. `select * from people where id is null`

Comment: Do `people.id` and `customer.id` have the same datatype?

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with your queries. Have you manually checked that the values you get from the `people` table *actually* exist in the `customers` table? Might the customers have a `people_id` field? Or people have a `customers_id` field? How big are these tables? Can you show us all the values from each table? *[Right now the only reason you don't get any results is that no customers have the same id as any of the people.]*

Comment: Andomar - There are some that are null.;

RB - They are both varchar;

Dems - There are values that match. If I take the results from my subquery and hard code those into my main query I get rows returned. It's only if I put the subquery itself into the main query that I get nothing back.

Comment: A join would be more efficient anyway.

Comment: @Boumbles - Then they're not the same values. They may appear the same, but they're not the same. Be they control characters, collation sequence differences (or whatever Oracle uses), leading/trailing spaces, data-type conversion issues, or something else, you query ***proves*** that they are ***not*** the same.

Comment: @Dems - It looks like you are right. I found that the persons table's data has something up with the data. It doesn't appear to be spaces.

Comment: try: select id, length(ID) from people;  You'll probably find you have some control chars in there (visual inspection in most IDEs will look like 'ABC', but its really 'ABC' + chr(0) or some other non-printable character.

Comment: @RB - I did just what you suggested before replying to Dems. That query returns nothing. I think there's some kind of character before or after what is stored there.

Comment: @tbone the length is 1 more than what I can see. I'm thinking the best way to get around this is to select only alphanumeric characters from persons. Is there a way to select only alphanumeric characters? I know how to trim those using translate but I'm not sure how to translate the non-alphanumerics. I've done some googling but everybody suggests creating a function, due to the way our system parses SQL, we can't do that. If this is impossible then we'll have to make sure the data that gets imported is cleaned up before we try to play with it.

Comment: @Boumbles No, the best way is to cleanup the data in people.  You're not (and won't be) the only user of this data.  You don't want everyone else who uses this to create some strange select (or worse, some custom function) every time, not to mention creating constraints and other good things you're paying good money for.  Do the right thing and cleanup the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this on people table (test in dev env of course):

```
update people set ID = regexp_replace(ID, '[[:cntrl:]]','');
commit;
```

Then try your queries again (and try using a join instead).

This should work on 11g, not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing. Some non printable characters are being put into the database when the data's loaded.

Answer (score 1):

so it could be that your ids are strings with trailing spaces.
try this instead:

```
select a.id, a.other_relevant_fields from customers a, people b 
where TRIM(a.id)=TRIM(b.id)
```

Comment: Oddly, this also does not work. However, if I remove the a.id=b.id and compare the ids from a and b that are returned, I can see they are the same. I just took a look and noticed that the max length of the columns is different.

Comment: Are the columns defined as `varchar2` or `char`.

Comment: they're varchar2. Originally one had a size of 150, the other only 60. I re sized it so they're both 150 now but I still get no results.

Comment: can you re-create the issue in a couple of test tables & provide an sql dump ?